# Pull down menus not appearing on Visual Studio 2010 after debug session

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-10

I would like to continue running Visual Studio 2010 on a new Windows 10 PC, in order to maintain some older projects, which I'm not ready to bring across to VS2015 yet.

However, on windows 10, I find that all of the drop down menus (and right-click context menus) stop appearing after running after a debug session. The only way to get them back again is to exit visual studio and re-launch it.

When clicking any of the File/Edit/etc menus in the top bar, the item will appear highlighted, but the menu that should appear below is completely invisible. Note this is not the same issue that is talked about at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653315/ui-gets-messed-up (which seems to be garbled menus) - mine are not there at all.

I've followed the advice there anyway, to disable hardware acceleration in the VS GUI, but I'm still having the same problem.

Any suggestions?

ADDITIONAL INFO (Edit):

- I should add that the PC (laptop) in question is a Thinkpad Yoga 460 with an NVidia GeForce 940M display adapter with switchable graphics (Intel HD Graphics 520).
- I have tried using the NVidia control panel to force VS2010 to use the intel graphics, and I have also tried the reverse (forcing it to use the NVidia). The problem still occurs either way.
- The menus stop working as soon as a debug session is entered (rather than on return from debug)

Comment: Not sure if it will help but something a bit similar to this also happened to me once and I found a few of the problems and fixed them on `form.designer.cs` and till this day have no clue what cause it because I only keep researching and did no try to ask SO yet.

Comment: Hi P.Pat, can you elaborate on what you fixed? I assume the problems were specific to one of your projects? I find this problem with menus affects every project I try to load, even a console program (with no winforms or WPF forms). Note also that I'm talking about the menus in the Visual Studio GUI, not menus in my programs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry I forgot to edit and add about context menu of GUI side, about that part where its all blank after debug I kind of did some things on Tools>Customize>Commands Tab and other things in Tools>Option which I don't exactly remember in details.

Comment: In case it helps anyone - in a fit of desperation (and following P.Pat's idea that it might be something menu/toolbar customisation related), I used the import/export settings option in VS2010 to reset all options to defaults. That fixed the problem with the menus. I've since re-imported all of my settings *except* the options branch and things are still good.

Comment: @DanielScott -- you should consider posting your solution as answer.

Comment: Hi David, I was meaning to do that. Done now! :) Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems one of my visual studio settings had caused the problem with the invisible/missing drop down menus.

I had imported all visual studio settings from my previous machine (using the Tools --> import/export settings option).

Resetting all Visual studio settings to defaults fixed the menus. I found that re-importing my settings, *except* for the "options" branch maintained the working menus.

I could dig further and try to figure out which specific setting from the "options" branch is causing the problem, but I'm leaving it here: I've got coding to do! :)